# How do I write an asynchronous function which polls a resource and returns when it's ready or otherwise retries in a few seconds?

Tags: async-await, rust

I want to write an asynchronous function which repeatedly polls a resource from the web and returns when it's ready. I am implementing it using [`future::poll_fn`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.17/futures/future/fn.poll_fn.html):

```
#![feature(async_await)]

/*
[dependencies]
rand = "0.7.0"
futures-preview = "=0.3.0-alpha.18"
*/

use futures::future;
use rand;
use std::task::Poll;

enum ResourceStatus {
    Ready,
    NotReady,
}
use ResourceStatus::*;

// Mocking the function requesting a web resource
fn poll_web_resource() -> ResourceStatus {
    if rand::random::<f32>() < 0.1 {
        Ready
    } else {
        NotReady
    }
}

async fn async_get_resource() {
    // do other works
    future::poll_fn(|ctx| match poll_web_resource() {
        Ready => Poll::Ready(()),
        NotReady => Poll::Pending,
    })
    .await
}

fn main() {
    futures::executor::block_on(async_get_resource());
}
```

It doesn't work because the task gets parked forever when `poll_web_resource()` returns `NotReady`. One way to solve it is to wake the task every time it returns `Pending`:

```
future::poll_fn(|ctx| match poll_web_resource() {
    Ready => Poll::Ready(()),
    NotReady => {
        ctx.waker().wake_by_ref();
        Poll::Pending
    }
})
.await
```

This creates loads of unnecessary requests. For my use case, the ideal situation would be request the resource every few seconds when it's not ready. Here's my current workaround:

```
future::poll_fn(|ctx| match poll_web_resource() {
    Ready => Poll::Ready(()),
    NotReady => {
        let waker = ctx.waker().clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep(Duration.from_millis(5000));
            waker.wake();
        });
        Poll::Pending
    }
})
.await
```

This works, but it uses an extra thread just for tracking the timeout. I think there should be a better way to do it. How can I achieve the same goal more idiomatically?

Comment: *Why* are you using the lower-level interface of `poll_fn`? Note that you aren't using the [`Context`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.17/futures/task/struct.Context.html), which is how you register interest in being woken up when something changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `async` / `await` keywords, write a loop that exits when the resource is available, or waits when it's not. Waiting can be accomplished with Tokio's [`Delay`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.0-alpha.1/tokio/timer/struct.Delay.html):

```
#![feature(async_await)]

use futures; // 0.3.0-alpha.17
use rand; // 0.7.0
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::timer; // 0.2.0-alpha.1

enum ResourceStatus {
    Ready,
    NotReady,
}
use ResourceStatus::*;

async fn async_get_resource() {
    const SLEEP_TIME: Duration = Duration::from_secs(1);

    loop {
        match poll_web_resource() {
            Ready => return,
            NotReady => {
                // Don't actually use println in production async code.
                println!("Waiting...");
                timer::Delay::new(tokio::clock::now() + SLEEP_TIME).await;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn poll_web_resource() -> ResourceStatus {
    if rand::random::<f32>() < 0.1 {
        Ready
    } else {
        NotReady
    }
}

fn main() {
    let runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().expect("Unable to create the runtime");
    let _resource = runtime.block_on(async_get_resource());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I wanted!